# Quel serait un synonyme de « désinhibé» et une autre façon de tourner la phrase citée dans les détails?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique, synonymes, formulation, reformulation

Quand tu es désinhibé sous l’emprise de l’alcool ou d’une drogue, est-ce que tu es porté à aller vers les autres plus aisément, deviens-tu plus entreprenant, gagnes-tu en confiance en toi, bref la désinhibition t’amène-t-elle a créer des liens sociaux plus facilement et à t’exprimer et à te comporter plus librement?

Comment: Se lâcher la bride peut-être ? Trop fort ?

Comment: Je dirais plutôt "désinhibé *par* l'alcool..." mais "désinhibé" est bien le terme adéquat, pourquoi en vouloir un autre ?

Comment: Pour avoir des synonymes en réserve. En écrivant la phrase qui précède, j’ai trouvé un synonyme: perdre sa réserve!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Différents sens, différents niveaux de langue : se relâcher, se débrider, se décoincer, être décomplexé par, abdiquer toute retenue, quitter sa réserve, etc. Tout dépend de la tournure de la phrase, et du sens exact que tu veux donner.